# How to build math libraries of glibc package?

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, glibc, configure, libm

I already know how to build the new version of Glibc (e.g. 2.3) beside the older version (e.g. 2.19). 
I followed the instructions in `https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Glibc-Install-HOWTO/`

But rather compiling whole libraries in Glibc, I only want to build math libraries (libm.so).

How can I only recompile libm.so in ubuntu?

The second question is that possible to recompile that specific part (maths) in glibc using the clang compiler? 
I found that I cannot recompile the whole Glibc using clang because of standards compliance and etc.

Answer (score 0):

`libm` depends on internals in the dynamic loader and `libc`, for example for IFUNC resolvers. You cannot simply take `libm` from a newer version and use install it on a system with an older glibc version. A while back, a few patches were proposed to optionally enables this:

- [Introduce `--enable-math-noprivate`](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2018-05/msg00501.html)
- [math: Use local `strto_*nan` function in `nan*` for `CONFIG_MATH_NOPRIVATE`](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2018-05/msg00541.html)
- [math: Merge `strtod_nam_*.h` into `math-type-macros-*.h`](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2018-05/msg00540.html) (This one was actually merged.)

Even with those patches, it was still necessary to build glibc with `--disable-multi-arch`, incurring a significant performance loss for some math functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.