# Why does MinGW GCC use x87 80bit FP library code for atan2, cos, exp & sin?

Tags: gcc, floating-point, mingw, avx, x87

I have a curious problem porting working numerical code from Intel 2023 & MSC Visual C++ 2022.
The code compiled with GCC is perfectly accurate (too accurate) since some library calls are working in full 80bit floating point precision - notably sqrt, sin and cos. I can verify this by tracing into the library calls with gdb using TUI to disassemble the library code execution.

It also shows up in the benchmark timings since x87 atan2, cos, exp & sin are all ~100 cycles and sqrt is ~80 cycles. The corresponding timings on SSE/AVX2 code are under 50 and mostly around 20-30 cycles.

Curiously tan, atan **are** compiled using AVX2. But cos, sin, sqrt and atan2 are using legacy x87 code inside a GCC system library. I have tried this with both the 32 bit port and the 64 bit version and have the same problem in both. I'm a novice on GCC so I may have overlooked something. I'm  using the default MinGW port version 13.1.0 (MinGW-W64 i686-ucrt-posix-dwarf) on Windows which may have its own peculiarities.

As an aside I just noticed that MSC 2022 sometimes codes x87 sqrt even with all gofaster optimisations and AVX2 code enabled since that is also an outlier in the benchmark timings that I hadn't noticed before. Intel compiles it to the native sqrtsd and is very much faster as a result. I went back to MSC x86 for inline assembler to confirm benchmark timings for the x87 trig instructions.

Compiler options are:
`gcc -c -O3 -Ofast -march=native -mavx2 -mfpmath=sse benchmark.cpp`

Linking is taking whatever the GCC default system libraries are and that seems to be the problem - my code or any system code that inlines generates SSE or AVX2 code so that tan and atan are OK but any that generate a library call are executing x87 instructions for the transcendental function in full 80 bit precision. I think it might be related to this thread which is the closest I could find:

[Why does MinGW-w64 floating-point precision depend on winpthreads version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67382785/why-does-mingw-w64-floating-point-precision-depend-on-winpthreads-version)

I want to force it to use a different FP library using entirely AVX2 or SSE2 code or recompile the existing ones with something like the `-march=native -mavx2` and `-Ofast`. Speed is more important than precise standards compliance here. There is a lot of trig involved.

It is entirely possible that I have linked the wrong default library in GCC. I have a sort of work around based on incorporating BSD trig library functions sourcecode but that isn't elegant.

I could post a code sample for the benchmark if someone wants to try it on their system but it would be a bit longer than seems normal here. I'm hoping that someone already knows the answer...

These are benchmarks in machine cycles for the primitive trig operations with AVX2 code gen MSC 2022 vs GCC 13.0.1. It was run on an Intel i5-12600 with maximum optimisation on both compilers.

|  | MSC | GCC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| atan | 12 | 13 |
| atan2 | 27 | 122 |
| log | 11 | 76 |
| exp | 11 | 136 |
| sin | 14 | 115 |
| cos | 13 | 117 |
| sincos | 19 | 127 |
| tan | 18 | 20 |

The ones using x87 code stand out a mile ~+100 cycles compared to where they should be.

I want to get the code using the right floating point library when compiled `-O3 -Ofast -mavx2`

Here is minimal sample code that shows my problem and a snapshot of the disassembly in GDB which shows how sin has become x87 FSIN etc. The other way to test if you are similarly afflicted is to benchmark sin(x) and tan(x) in your favourite profiler if tan timing is ~20 cycles and sin ~40 then you are OK (tan ~2x faster than sin). Any trig function 100+ cycles and it is slow x87 code.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"

// Toy use of sin & tan to see if they compile using SSE2 or x87

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
double x, y;
if (argc>1) x = atof(argv[1]); else x = 3.1415926535/2;
y = sin(x);
printf("sin of %g is %18.10g\n", x, y);
x = x/2;
y = tan(x);
printf("tan of %g is %18.10g\n", x, y);
}
```

Disassembly of sin routine using x87 code from GDB (tan is OK)

```
 <__sinl_internal>        fldt   (%rdx)                                                                
 <__sinl_internal+2>      fsin                                                                       
 <__sinl_internal+4>      fnstsw %ax                                                                
 <__sinl_internal+6>      test   $0x400,%eax                                                        
 <__sinl_internal+11>     jne    0x7ff656332e6b                              
 <__sinl_internal+13>     mov    %rcx,%rax                                                          
 <__sinl_internal+16>     movq   $0x0,0x8(%rcx)                                                     
 <__sinl_internal+24>     fstpt  (%rcx)                                                             
 <__sinl_internal+26>     ret
```

I am fairly convinced now that @emacsdrivesmenuts is right and I have to rebuild the default system maths library with the correct FP optimisation under Mingw to fix this but I have no idea how to do that!

Thanks for any enlightenment!

Comment: "Speed is more important than precise standards compliance here. " --> OK. Please _quantify_.  How much imprecision is tolerable or what minimum speed is required.  Else use `float versions: `atan2f(), cosf(), expf() & sinf()`.

Comment: GCC should be inlining `sqrt()` as `sqrtsd` with at worst a compare/branch in case of NaN if you don't enable `-fno-math-errno` (https://godbolt.org/z/6aW4n57ME).  (Which is on as part of `-ffast-math` or `-Ofast`.)  The 32-bit calling convention forces FP return in `st0`, which makes things slower if functions can't inline.  The other functions won't inline, and 32-bit MinGW is maybe aiming for compat with old machines without SSE2 in its libraries?  I notice you're using i686 GCC; if you want numerical performance, 64-bit code is usually better.

Comment: I hope I am replying in the right place - and thank you to whoever sorted out my mangled table. It looked OK in the editor but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Quantifying - I don't need Nan handling or range reduction - arguments will be |x|<=pi denorms are possible but only cause a performance hit. I'd like 0.5lsb accuracy double precision trig but could probably live with 2 lsb error @chux. sqrt did inline in x64 and that compiler IDs as MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh. It is close to Intel speed on my code but still same old slow if log, pow, sin or cos are used. exp is 10% slower in x64!

Comment: Usually, these functions are implemented by `libm`, and options like `-O3` are not multilib options.  This means that such options have no effect on multilib selections.  So you'll have to investigate how `libm` was being built and maybe build your own version with adjusted options.

Comment: @MartinBrown: Use @ when replying to people so they see your replies.  That was my edit, as you can see from the edit history (bottom middle of the post).  I'm surprised the table looked right in the preview.  Maybe you didn't look at the preview, only the actual markdown editor textbox.  Markdown gets rendered into HTML, not like an ASCII text file.  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @chux I tried your suggestion of using floats throughout out of curiosity. The timings were to say the least *interesting*.  Original code mycbrt double 190, all float using system cbrtf 223!, changed it back to mycbrt (float version) AXV2 122, AVX 130 and best of all SSE2 108.  (times in machine cycles). It seems memory bandwidth may play a part in the timings for non-vectorisable code.

Comment: @MartinBrown Changing to `cbrtf()` may be insufficient as all the nearby code needs to change to `float` for real benefit.  Consider `cbrt(x/3.0)` vs `cbrtf(x/3.0)` vs. `cbrtf(x/3.0f)`.  Only the last is really an all `float` code.  Posting an example of code would help move review from theoretical to actual.

Comment: @chux Sorry for the ambiguity. Yes it was an entirely 32 bit float implementation with all variables, constants and functions as floats. This makes the cubic solver a bit iffy on extreme test cases but I avoided them when benchmarking it. Timings represent IRL performance - system cbrt on GCC and MS are both poor for timing and accuracy. I'd have to start a new thread to post sample code  since it won't fit in a comment. Or can I  edit my original question to add a sample piece of code at this stage?  ~50 LOC
Reviewing it I have missed an f on the odd integer constant used in FP expressions.

Comment: @MartinBrown As answers have not arrived, there is more latitude in changing, adding to the question.  (when in doubt, append rather than change)  IAC, appending 50 LOC example would improve the post.  A [MCVE] that others can time is even better.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts (it does me too) Thanks for the hint.  I'm fairly convinced you are right but I have no idea how to go about doing that under MinGW. The closest I got to a how to was this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964628/how-to-build-math-libraries-of-glibc-package  and it is for Ubuntu rather than Mingw and warns of significant maths slow down if not done right. Also refers to .so files which I think must be Unix specific since I don't have any on my Win11 Mingw 13.1.0 install.

Comment: @chux I read the minimal reproducible example guide and decided to stay focussed on this particular problem of atan2,cos,exp sin being x87 and slow in the Mingw build. I will start another thread for code with weird timing behaviour on different compilers. I have some very interesting ones to share and would appreciate feedback. It will take me a while to construct minimal code examples that show the most interesting behaviour. BTW thanks for the idea of floats it may provide a speedup that I had overlooked. Cubic solver needs work though to cope with smaller float exponent.

Comment: @MartinBrown To well investigate FP, consider 1) using output to show all the precision/bits `"%a"` or `"%.17g"`.  2) There are closer values to 90 degrees `x = 3.1415926535/2;` --> use min 17 significant digits: 3.1415926535897932/2.  The point being that in trying to speed things up, sometimes the best functional answer gets lost.

Comment: @chux since this is to investigate  a system library coding fault I just put a value in as a default there that would be OK. M_PI requires an extra line. I wouldn't put it past compilers on -O3 to generate code that loads const x and const binary representation of sin(x). The important thing is that the compiler can't tell what value it will be given in argv[1] so that path has to call the sin and tan routines. I considered just using argc instead but thought that **too** minimalist. BTW what timing do you get for sin(x), tan(x) ?